# Fallback on binding warning not working

Tags: xaml, binding, warnings, fallback

I have some bindings warning that I can't solve:

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : **Cannot retrieve value using the
>   binding and no valid fallback value exists**; using default instead.
>   BindingExpression:Path=AddNewObjectCommand; DataItem=null; target
>   element is 'ButtonWithIcon' (Name='uc'); target property is
>   'ButtonCommand' (type 'ICommand')

My understanding is that I should use a fallback value. This works with simple object types, however don't know how to handle this for complex objects like lists, or in that case commands.

Here is what I have tried, with no luck:

```
<controls:ButtonWithIcon ButtonCommand="{Binding CancelCommand, FallbackValue={x:Null}}" />
```

Would you have any thought on this?

Thank you in advance!